# Excel SUMPRODUCT Formula not working

Tags: excel, formula

I have a very difficult Spreadsheet that I need to figure out a formula to get an answer. The Spreadsheet can have multiple rows (each row is a policy) In the rows there are several columns (A, B, C, D , E, F, G) Columns D, E, and G can have one of 4 answers (Right, Left, Up, or Down).

I want to create a formula that tells me how may policies (rows) have and answer of up or down in any one of the 3 Columns (D, E, or F). If it appears in multiple column I only want to count it once. Can anyone help with this formula?

I have to do this all in one field as the Calculations all appear at the top of the spreadsheet and the rest spreadsheet is being populated from a canned report from another system that we have to cut and paste.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.Really need to get this working. Thanks

Comment: ... and yet you didn't think it was important to show the formula you are working on. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=SUM(IF(MMULT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2:F100,{"Up","Down"},0))+0,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(D2:F100)^0))>0,1))
```

Adjust the range accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Jsleshem What would you suggest is a more efficient formula?